# How to add to the end of text column through sql?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create an sql query that adds a string to the end of the cell. Right now I have this.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET $column1= $column1 + $newstring1, $column2 = $column2 + $newstring2, $column3 = $column3 + $newstring3, WHERE username = $user_username";
```

The values of $newstring1, $newstring2, and $newstring3 are formatted like "155:2,"

The idea is to add delimiters to each entry so I can easily sort them later. Right now I'm getting a syntax error on my query, but I'm new to php. Is the error because when the database is empty, there is no original variable and therefore I need to INSERT INTO instead of UPDATE, or is the comma in the string itself creating the error and do I need to somehow concatenate it?

I'm more used to C# than PHP so I'm not sure the proper way to format that type of query.

Comment: If you want to add more entries for a record, best way to do it is to use another table and have a one to many relationship and just insert a new record for each new value and not use delimiters.  Then you wont have to parse anything to get the data.

Comment: The problem is I'm going to be inserting a large number of entries, and each cell will be thousands of characters. I could just retrieve the data from the sql table, alter it in C#, and then repost it. I just wanted to see if there was a simpler way.

Comment: I dont think that is simpler (faster to finish programming and simpler as in less work to accomplish it) but not better solution.  Trust me doing it right the first time will pay off and make it less of a headache in the future, plus may need to do it later anyway and doing it now will save you haveing to rewrite it all and backfill the data later

Comment: adding another string **at the end** of an already long string *"so I can easily sort them later"* is not going to be a very efficient way to sort anyway. I suggest you include some **sample data** and an **expected result** I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)